# How to run a c# web service from a raspberry pi 3?

Tags: pi-3, c#, mono

I want to write a simple web service in c# using Visual Studios, and deploy this service from a Raspberry Pi 3. I know mono is a tool that runs .NET code on Linux machines, but all of the examples I've seen are just running simple C# console applications.

Is it possible to run a whole c# web service? It will not be getting a lot (or any) traffic and is more of a just a personal project for fun, so I don't care about maximizing performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using mono to run entire web applications developed on visual studio on a Linux nginx web server running on an AWS instance (therefore, running on x86_64).

Basically, you can run anything if you follow the guidelines described on mono-project (there is a list of what is not supported). What do you need are the packages compiled for ARM7HL and you're probably fine.

You can find all you need about it here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/aspnet/